# Twilio Programmable Video and Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, twilio, twilio-video

I'm developing a mobile app that must implement Twilio Programmable Video.
I have developed a backend with Twilio SDK 5.24.2 in Laravel PHP Framework and that works well.
In the mobile app, I have installed the twilio-video 2.0.0-beta4 package through npm and developed a page based in the example in "video-quickstart-js-1.x". The problem is when Twilio tries to connect to the room, the error in the console is as follows (at the end of the log):

```
sip.ua | configuration parameters after validation:
sip.ua | · viaHost: "2lknee65ci64.invalid"
sip.ua | · uri: sip:28cd13aa-0cbc-45d3-85e7-0279ce6869f6@endpoint.twilio.com
sip.ua | · wsServers: [{"ws_uri":"wss://endpoint.twilio.com","sip_uri":"<sip:endpoint.twilio.com;transport=ws;lr>","weight":0,"status":0,"scheme":"WSS"}]
sip.ua | · password: NOT SHOWN
sip.ua | · registerExpires: 600
sip.ua | · register: false
sip.ua | · registrarServer: sip:endpoint.twilio.com
sip.ua | · wsServerMaxReconnection: 3
sip.ua | · wsServerReconnectionTimeout: 4
sip.ua | · connectionRecoveryMinInterval: 2
sip.ua | · connectionRecoveryMaxInterval: 30
sip.ua | · keepAliveInterval: 30
sip.ua | · extraSupported: ["room-signaling","timer"]
sip.ua | · usePreloadedRoute: false
sip.ua | · userAgentString: "SIP.js/0.7.7"
sip.ua | · iceCheckingTimeout: 5000
sip.ua | · noAnswerTimeout: 60000
sip.ua | · stunServers: ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]
sip.ua | · turnServers: []
sip.ua | · traceSip: true
sip.ua | · hackViaTcp: false
sip.ua | · hackIpInContact: false
sip.ua | · hackWssInTransport: true
sip.ua | · hackAllowUnregisteredOptionTags: true
sip.ua | · hackCleanJitsiSdpImageattr: false
sip.ua | · hackStripTcp: false
sip.ua | · contactTransport: "wss"
sip.ua | · forceRport: false
sip.ua | · autostart: false
sip.ua | · rel100: "none"
sip.ua | · replaces: "none"
sip.ua | · mediaHandlerFactory: function promisifiedFactory () {
var mediaHandler = mediaHandlerFactory.apply(this, arguments);
function patchMethod (methodName) {
  var method = mediaHandler[methodName];
  if (method.length > 1) {
  var callbacksFirst = methodName === 'getDescription';
  mediaHandler[methodName] = SIP.Utils.promisify(mediaHandler, methodName, callbacksFirst);
  }
}
patchMethod('getDescription');
patchMethod('setDescription');
return mediaHandler;
}
sip.ua | · authenticationFactory: undefined
sip.ua | · allowLegacyNotifications: false
sip.ua | · instanceId: "7ef84624-118d-4cbc-838e-5093ef3907bb"
sip.ua | · sipjsId: "5249a"
sip.ua | · hostportParams: "endpoint.twilio.com"
sip.ua | · authorizationUser: "28cd13aa-0cbc-45d3-85e7-0279ce6869f6"
sip.ua | · media: undefined
INFO in [connect #1]: Connecting to a Room
DEBUG in [connect #1]: Options: {wsServer: "wss://endpoint.twilio.com", abortOnIceServersTimeout: false, createLocalTracks: ƒ, environment: "prod", iceServersTimeout: 3000, …}
INFO in [NTSIceServerSource #1]: Created a new NTSIceServerSource
DEBUG in [NTSIceServerSource #1]: ECS server: https://ecs.us1.twilio.com
INFO in [connect #1]: LocalTracks were not provided, so they will be acquired automatically before connecting to the Room. LocalTracks will be released if connecting to the Room fails or if the Room is disconnected

getusermedia.js:22 [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.
WARN in [createLocalTracks #1]: Call to getUserMedia failed: DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).
INFO in [connect #1]: Error while connecting to a Room: DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).
consultation-video.ts:137 Could not connect to Twilio: Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features).
```

My code in Ionic is as follows:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ApiServiceProvider } from '../../providers/api-service';
import TwilioVideo from 'twilio-video';

export class VideoPage
{
  public roomSid: string;
  public activeRoom: any;
  public twilioAccessToken: string;

  @ViewChild('remoteMedia') remoteMedia: any;
  @ViewChild('localMedia') localMedia: any;
  @ViewChild('buttonLeave') buttonLeave: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private apiServiceProvider: ApiServiceProvider
  ) {
    this.roomSid = navParams.get('room_sid');
    this.joinToRoom(this.roomSid);
  }

  joinToRoom(roomSid: string) {
    let videoCallData = {
      room_sid: roomSid
    };

    this.apiServiceProvider.joinVideoRoom(videoCallData)
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.twilioAccessToken = result.access_token;
        this.generateVideoCall();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  generateVideoCall() {
    let connectOptions = {
      name: this.roomSid
    };

    connectOptions['logLevel'] = 'debug';

    TwilioVideo.connect(this.twilioAccessToken, connectOptions)
    .then(this.roomJoined, function(error) {
      console.log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
    });
  }

  roomJoined(room: any) {
    this.activeRoom = room;

    // Attach LocalParticipant's Tracks, if not already attached.
    var previewContainer = this.localMedia;
    if (!previewContainer.querySelector('video')) {
      this.attachParticipantTracks(this.activeRoom.localParticipant, previewContainer);
    }

    // Attach the Tracks of the Room's Participants.
    this.activeRoom.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
      console.log("Already in Room: '" + participant.identity + "'");
      let previewContainer = this.remoteMedia;
      this.attachParticipantTracks(participant, previewContainer);
    });

    // When a Participant joins the Room, log the event.
    this.activeRoom.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
      console.log("Joining: '" + participant.identity + "'");
    });

    // When a Participant adds a Track, attach it to the DOM.
    this.activeRoom.on('trackAdded', function(track, participant) {
      console.log(participant.identity + " added track: " + track.kind);
      var previewContainer = this.remoteMedia;
      this.attachTracks([track], previewContainer);
    });

    // When a Participant removes a Track, detach it from the DOM.
    this.activeRoom.on('trackRemoved', function(track, participant) {
      console.log(participant.identity + " removed track: " + track.kind);
      this.detachTracks([track]);
    });

    // When a Participant leaves the Room, detach its Tracks.
    this.activeRoom.on('participantDisconnected', function(participant) {
      console.log("Participant '" + participant.identity + "' left the room");
      this.detachParticipantTracks(participant);
    });

    // Once the LocalParticipant leaves the room, detach the Tracks of all Participants, including that of the LocalParticipant.
    this.activeRoom.on('disconnected', function() {
      console.log('Left room');

      if (this.previewTracks) {
        this.previewTracks.forEach(function(track) {
          track.stop();
        });
        this.previewTracks = null;
      }

      this.detachParticipantTracks(this.activeRoom.localParticipant);
      this.activeRoom.participants.forEach(this.detachParticipantTracks);
    });
  }

  // Attach the Participant's Tracks to the DOM.
  attachParticipantTracks(participant, container) {
    var tracks = Array.from(participant.tracks.values());
    this.attachTracks(tracks, container);
  }

  // Attach the Tracks to the DOM.
  attachTracks(tracks, container) {
    tracks.forEach(function(track) {
      container.appendChild(track.attach());
    });
  }

  // Detach the Tracks from the DOM.
  detachTracks(tracks) {
    tracks.forEach(function(track) {
      track.detach().forEach(function(detachedElement) {
        detachedElement.remove();
      });
    });
  }

  // Detach the Participant's Tracks from the DOM.
  detachParticipantTracks(participant) {
    var tracks = Array.from(participant.tracks.values());
    this.detachTracks(tracks);
  }

  // Leave Room.
  leaveRoomIfJoined() {
    if (this.activeRoom) {
      this.activeRoom.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML has the next structure:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div #remoteMedia></div>

  <div #localMedia></div>

  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button ion-button icon-only round #buttonLeave (click)="leaveCall($event)">
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

I run the app in the device with this code:

```
ionic cordova run android --device --livereload
```

How can I solve the shown error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to implement this on my project, but I get an error: "Could not start video source". Did you use cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview to make it work on your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this error, the right command for executing the Ionic app is:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

The --livereload must not be used, because in this case the app access the develop machine as insecure origin.